# parsing two arrays returned by a web-service with JSON

Tags: arrays, web-services, json, ios

my web-service return me an array composed of two arrays, here how it looks like on the web-service:

```
$finalArray=array($array1,$array2);
sendResponse(200,json_encode($finalArray));
```

each array contains a list of simple values :

```
array1{gazole,sp98,GPL,gazole+}
array2{TOTAL,SHELL,ESSO}
```

in my iPhone side, i would like to parse this and to put the content of each array on an NSArray, i used to do that :

```
//parse the response

       NSArray *array=[[request responseString]JSONValue];
```

i'm little confused for the rest, please help, thx in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the objectAtIndex method of NSArray.